# Bootstrap carousel with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, carrierwave

I am trying to make a slideshow using multiple photos that users uploaded through carrierwave.

This is my post/show.html.erb

```
<div id = "carousel-example-generic" class= "carousel slide" data-ride= "carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <% @photo_attachments.each do |p| %>
    <div class="item active">
        <%=image_tag p.avatar_url.to_s%>
    </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
  <% end %>
</div>
 .....
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
  </script>
```

I cannot figure it out the way to list one photo per slide:( It is still listing all the photos that I have to scroll :(

Answer (score 1):

You are applying active class to all photos that you use

```
div class="item active"
```

but it should be

```
div class="item"
```

and add this into your javascript

```
$( '.item:first' ).addClass( 'active');
```